# Creating a new page template in Typo3

Tags: typo3

I'm using Typo3 for the first time and have been asked to update a site built on it.

Making changes to existing templates so far has been OK since they were mainly CSS changes or replacing images. Now though I need to create a couple of new page templates.

What's the easiest way to go about this? The existing site has a home.html and layout.hmlt in the fileadmin directory. Do I need to create a new html file there, if so how do I use this as a new template for some of my pages?

I'm coming from a mainly WordPress background in terms of CMS (I've nearly given in a recoded the site as a WordPress site since I think it would be quicker at this stage) but I'd really prefer to figure this out.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I'm pulling my hair out trying to read through the documentation and getting nowhere. The site is using Typo3 version 4.4.6

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you add a new template to your page depends on how templating is handled. Sadly TYPO3 has a poor templating out of the box, so there is most likely an extension that does the job on your site.

Probably one of these:

- automaketemplate
- templa_voila
- flux & fluidpages

Check if one of these extension is installed and add a new page template according to the extensions manual or specify your question afterwards.

Edit:
If plain TYPO3 was used, you'll find something like

```
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEMPLATE
page.10 {
  file = fileadmin/myTemplate.html
}
```

in your Typoscript. You can add tmplate files like the ones that are already there. To use a different template on a page, you have to replace the `page.10.file` with the template you want to use. This can be done with a new template record (crated in backend via the template module). But this is a rather anoying procedure to change the template, because you have to create each time you want to change the page template for a page and its children. That is why mostly extensions are used for this.

The out of the box situation gets better with newer TYPO3 versions but in 4.4.6 there are no Backend Layouts that could be uses for a template switch ot something like that.

In Addition to change the mere file you have to adjust the subparts or marker that are filled with the content. You'll find that configured in your TypoScript as well

Comment: Thanks! I can't seem to see any extensions being used for handling the templates. I've tried specifying the template in the list > template > setup but it loads two templates now. 


I'm using: page.33 = TEMPLATE
page.33.template = FILE
page.33.template.file = fileadmin/template-name.html

Comment: Thanks a million for that! I used the above with a conditional statement to change the template for the right pages. It doesn't feel right but it will do for now. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it!